# Interval overlapping - falling ball problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on a problem related to the interval overlapping algorithm. A short description would be:

We have a 2D grid where we can place/remove planks in each loop iteration. When we drop a ball from the top (S position can be random), I need to determine what's the deepest position it can fall to.

[image: grid]

I have experimented with the classic interval overlapping algorithm, but I'm almost certain I could really make this more optimal. I have tried looping through the V axis from the top, and checking if the stick intervals overlap so the whole "hole" is covered.

One optimization I see first, is that I could keep track of the minimum V position and start the loop at that.

I've also been given a hint that I should use a optimal data structure, that would "allow me to sort sticks by the Y coordinate in each column". I am not sure that sorting by Y would help me at all - am I missing something?

Also, I've been reading up some algorithms and it sees like a segment tree would also be able to solve this. Would it be feasible to try that approach as well, or am I just shooting in the dark here?

Comment: Hi. I am afraid that "the classic interval overlapping algorithm" might not be as classic as you think it is, at least not under that name. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Stef my bad - I guess there was a language barrier :)

basically just sorting the intervals by the first (if they are the same by the second) coordinate, then foreaching trough all of them and checking if the full interval is covered.

Comment: You are not shooting in the dark with the segment tree. Totally possible.

Comment: @Aldert would you mind sharing any hints on approaching it like that?
I know how to handle the tree (add/remove from it, that leaves are values in the "input array" and inner nodes are sums). 

Would I have to re-construct the tree for each height? I of course can't sort anything here in the Y axis, because I need to find the lowest position it can fall to.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following example based on your question. I only took your solid lines and call them Segments.

```
S1 (0,4) Y2
S2 (1,3) Y5
S3 (4,8) Y7
S4 (8,10) Y6
```

You can create a segment tree as below:

S=5:
Travel from the root node down to the leaves. At the root node 5 < 9 = true so we take a left turn, next node 5 < 8 = false so we go to right. We also record s1 as a segment found. Next node 5 < 4 = false, again we go to the right and we are at leaf 4 and find s3.
So we have 2 lines for which we have to check that the end points are >= 5, only for s3 this is the case. Y = 7 is the answer.

S=8: 8 < 8 = false, go to right. We find s4, 8 < 10 = true, go to left. We find leaf 8 with S3. We have S3 and S4 check if endpoint >= 8, for both this is true.  we find Y= 6 as minimum Y.

[image]